# How to treat a command output as text

Tags: bash, command, string, output

I need to compare a command output with a string.
This is the scenario:

```
pvs_var=$(pvs | grep "sdb1")
```

so pvs var is: /dev/sdb1 vg_name lvm2 a-- 100.00g 0

```
if [[ $($pvs_var | awk '{ print $2 }') = vg_name ]]; then
    do something
fi
```

The issue is that the output of the if statement is

```
-bash: /dev/sdb1: Permission denied
```

I don't understand this behavior. 
Thank you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are attempting to execute the contents of `$pvs_var` as a command, rather than passing the string to awk.

To fix this, add an `echo` or `printf` in your if statement:

```
if [[ $(echo "$pvs_var" | awk '{ print $2 }') = vg_name ]]; then
    do something
fi
```

Comment: Since the shell is bash, might as well `awk '{ print $2 }' <<<"$pvs_var"`

Comment: @D.BenKnoble: Even better, we can replace the double brackets with single brackets and then it’s POSIX compliant.

Comment: @Peschke With single brackets, you'd want to add double-quotes around the `$( )` expression.

Comment: You definitely want `printf` in the general case.  Echo can do strange things if the variable contains backslashes or starts with a dash.

Answer (score 4):

Get the output in JSON format, and then you'll be able to extract information in a more reliable way:

```
pv_info=$(pvs -o pv_all,vg_all --unit b --nosuffix --reportformat json)
sdb1_vg=$(
  printf '%s\n' "$pv_info" |
    jq -r '.report[].pv[]|select(.pv_name == "/dev/sdb1").vg_name'
)

if [ "$sdb1_vg" = vg_name ]; then...
```

Or use a proper programming language with a JSON library instead of a shell (`ksh93` does have JSON support though in its upcoming version).

(you need LVM 2.02.158 (2016) or newer for `--reportformat json`).

If it's just that one query you want to do, `pvs` can also do all the work for you:

```
sdb1_vg=$(
  pvs -o vg_name -S pv_name=/dev/sdb1 --no-heading --config 'log{prefix=""}'
)
```

(you need LVM 2.02.107 (2014) or newer for `-S`).

Also remember to [quote your variables](/q/171346) and [avoid `echo`](/q/65803).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to compare the VG from the output, then it might be easier to pre-process that:

```
# if you still need it
pvs_var=$(pvs | grep "sdb1") 
vg_name=$(pvs | grep "sdb1" | awk '{print $2}')
if [ "$vg_name" = "vg_name" ]; then
  echo do something
fi
```

What you were doing with

> $($pvs_var | awk '{ print $2 }')

was initiating a command substitution `$( ... )` whose first command was `$pvs_var`. Bash dutifully substituted the value of the variable and then attempted to execute it. That's not what you wanted.

Another alternative would be to send the variable as a here-string to the awk command:

```
# ...
if [ $(awk '{print $2}' <<< "$pvs_var") = "vg_name" ]; then
# ...
```

Here, the command substitution is calling awk and passing it input on stdin -- the contents of the `$pvs_var` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can try only with awk :

```
pvs | awk -v search='vg_name' '/sdb1/&&$2==search{exit 1}' || echo "ok"
```